# Law of excluded middle: mathematical philosophy

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Is it a contradiction, if

- mathematical objects are for me "mental constructions" -- like in intuitionism

but

- I accept classical mathematics and the Law oft excluded middle

?

Comment: If you accept the Law of the Excluded Middle, you have to come up with some other solution to Russel's paradox.  Rejecting Brower's suspension of 'not' is not rejecting his idea that mathematical operations are psychological habits and not laws of nature.  But it is not a good idea to hang onto a reasoning habit that leads you directly into paradox.

Comment: @jobermark What does LEM have to do with Russell's paradox? The derivation of a contradiction from naïve comprehension is intuitionistically valid.

Comment: @J.P. The paradox involves three steps.  You have to say "1) it is unambiguous what is meant for x not to be in x (free self reference).  2) construct the set of all x with x not in x (unbounded universal quantification). 3) either x is in x or x is not in x (LEM) and you get a contradiction."   So removing any of the steps solves the problem.  Set theory cripples unbounded universal quantification, intuitionism undercuts LEM, and ramification or sequencing of types limit free self-reference.  Each is a solution to this problem.

Comment: In intuitionism it is simply not true that either x has to be a member of itself or it has to not be a member of itself.  It can be undeterminable whether x is a member of itself.  "tertium datur".

Comment: By intuitionism, above, I mean Brower's proposed set of modifications, not the basic underlying idea.  But the other two proposed solutions are waaay too unintuitive and over-reconstructed to be considered natural psychological reactions to the world.  So, if you accept the basic premise of intuitionism, and reject suspension of LEM, you would need a truly novel approach to avoid the paradox.

Comment: @jobermark It's just false (and therefore misleading) to say that the paradox involves your step (3) (LEM). Let r be the Russell set. Suppose that r∈r, then ¬(r∈r), which is a contradiction, so by *intuitionistically valid* reductio, ¬(r∈r), and we discharge the assumption. Then, r∈r, and we have a contradiction, independent of any assumptions. At no stage is LEM used, all is used is the intuitionistically valid principle that if you can derive a contradiction from *p*, then you can infer ¬ *p*. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/914901/120446).

Comment: @J.P. This x is a SET, not an item.  It has some definition p.  Given that we do not know what p says, how you know that p itself contradicts not p?  If p is irreducibly of the form not q, we are safe.  After all "not q and not not q" do not contradict for an abstract q.  We cannot necessarily produce a proof that q is inherently contradictory if we choose it at random.  It is possible that the definition of x itself cannot be expressed without a negation and "x in x" is therefore indeterminate.  The formalism makes this sound stupid, but formalizations of intuitionism are not intuitionism.

Comment: @J.P.  More basically, with negation limited, you need to reconsider what you mean by a contradiction.  A contradiction is a fact that implies everything.  And without LEM, you cannot necessarily get from a single formal statement and its opposite to this implosion, unless you know the statement's form.  A provable statement and its proven negation will get you there, but a potentially false statement and its unprovable negation will not.

Comment: @jobermark Whatever you're suggesting is not standard intuitionism, and goes well beyond just rejecting LEM, which is what was at issue here.

Comment: @J.P. Whether you consider the set fuzzy, or membership within it fuzzy, without the LEM, you do not have the clarity to do what you need to do to get the contradiction.  Looking at truth value as non-fuzzy, without LEM, there are sets such that for all x if y is not in y, then y is in x. And there are sets such that for all x if it is not true that y is not in y, then y is omitted from x. But there is no unique set such that for all x, y is in y if and only if y is in x unless you assume LEM, because not (y not in y) does not imply y is in y.

Comment: Elements whose inclusion within themselves is classically true but unproveable would be excluded if we are enumerating by inclusion, and included if we are enumerating by exclusion, making it impossible to know whether they are in the set or not.  So looking at this in the BHK way, the set does not exist, and looking at it in the equivalent 'poly-alethian' way, the formal deduction you start with can be done, but intuitionistically, it has no meaning.

Comment: And this is not unique to intuitionism.  Any way you drop LEM allows for an extra truth value for propositions that are "not true, but not not true".  Since the elements of sets of sets are themselves defined by proposition, ANY way you drop LEM undercuts Russell's paradox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "mental construction":

- If you mean **mental** construction, i.e. just in mind, then there is no contradiction.
- If you mean mental **construction**, i.e. constructible step by step by a finite algorithm, then it is a contradiction.

**Added.**

1) **mental** construction: Mathematical objects are ideas, they do not exist as physical objects. Sophisticated concepts like Hilbert space or Riemann manifold have been created by man and fixed by definitions. Hence they are mental constructions. This opinion is not shared by all philosophers of mathematics. Instead, some keep alive the discussion whether mathematical objects have been invented or have been detected.

2) mental **construction**: Mathematicians from the school of intuitionism reject the existence of mathematical objects like the set of all natural numbers. They accept "potential" infinity like constructing one number after the other - without an end. But they reject "actual" infinity, which equals the cardinalty of the set of natural numbers taken as a whole. Instead, they request that any object must be constructible. Therefore they do not accept the method of indirect proof. It builds on the law of the excluded middle.

Comment: Why does this answer has a 'down vote'?

Comment: The second point is not quite honest.  Intuitionism is not constructivism, it allows for the idea of the set of all integers, and proposes ideas that arise from intuition: for instance the idea of a real number as "an infinite pre-determined free-flowing stream of digits", which make no sense from the point of view of constructivism.  Constructivism captures the intention behind continuity with an approximation.  Intuitionism notes that the definition is not very useful in that it makes all functions continuous, and chooses to focus its attention elsewhere.  The two are not the same thing.

Comment: I should have said it allows for the idea of collections which contain all integers, not a unique such entity, and with no single best one among them.  But still, it is not constructivism, because constructively, there is not an ambiguous collection of such things, there is no such thing.